# how can you eliminate permutations between columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have table columns one (idprocess) point to columns two (idporcess1) and point to columns tree (idprocess2).

```
id    idprocess        idporcess1    idprocess2
1      15                  16          17                  <==  A
2      15                  16          19                  <==  B
3      15                  20          23
4      14                  16          17
6      16                  15          80                  <== C
7      17                  15           49                 <== D
8      23                  16           20                 <== E
```

I need a SQL query that returns this: row c and row D, so with number  idprocess(16) and  idprocess(17 )

because row c : idprocess(16) references again ipdprocess1(15)
because row c : idprocess(17 ) references agin ipdprocess1(15)

please help
 i want only to eleminate circular referencial in tree

Comment: What do you mean by "permation"?

Comment: permutation betwenn column (idprocess and iprocess1) and (idprocess and iprocess2)

Comment: Why do those two rows get selected? Your criteria are unclear.

Comment: wow - hard to decypher.. i think this means a hierarchic query.

Comment: Are you trying to identify circular references? In other words, idprocess 15 points to idprocess1 16 and idprocess 16 points to idprocess1 15.

Comment: yes i want to identfy circular referces

Comment: Edited the question title to make the intent clearer. Anyway, unless you have a known limit to the length of a reference chain, you'll have to do this in multiple queries.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then your example is wrong: there is no (15,17), so there is no permutation of (17,15). If you are after something else, then the term "permutation" is probably wrong.

Comment: Do you only care about direct circular references (i.e. 15 points to 17, 17 points to 15) or do you also need to find indirect circular references (i.e. 15 points to 17, 17 points to 20, 20 points to 15)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to find rows where the first two columns are permutated, this will do the job:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_tbl t
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_tbl t1 WHERE t1.idprocess = t.idprocess1 AND t1.idprocess1 = t.idprocess)
 ORDER BY t.id;
```

---

Alternative interpretation:
If you want all rows where `idprocess1` has been listed in `idprocess` before (before = smaller id), then you can:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_tbl t
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_tbl t1 WHERE t1.id < t.id AND t1.idprocess = t.idprocess1)
 ORDER BY t.id;
```

You wouldn't call that "permutation", though.

Comment: @AbdelillahFarka: there was a mistake in my first version, should be fixed now.

Comment: @AbdelillahFarka: Sorry, I do not understand. If you are having a hard time to express what you are after, then please **edit your question** with an example that shows the exact result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit ambiguous but I tried to understand it on my own and prepared the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEMP
where C2 IN ( Select C2 FROM TEMP group by C2 having count(C2) > 1 )
OR C3 IN ( Select C3 FROM TEMP group by C3 having count(C3) > 1 )
```